# PostgreSQL Pivot by Last Date

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

I need to make a PIVOT table from Source like this table

```
FactID  UserID  Date    Product QTY
1         11    01/01/2020  A   600
2         11    02/01/2020  A   400
3         11    03/01/2020  B   500
4         11    04/01/2020  B   200
6         22    06/01/2020  A   1000
7         22    07/01/2020  A   200
8         22    08/01/2020  B   300
9         22    09/01/2020  B   100
```

Need Pivot Like this where Product QTY is QTY by **Last Date**

```
UserID  A   B
11      400 200
22      200 100
```

My try PostgreSQL

```
Select 
        UserID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Product='A' THEN 'QTY' END) AS 'A',
        MAX(CASE WHEN Product='B' THEN 'QTY' END) AS 'B'
FROM table
GROUP BY UserID
```

And Result

```
UserID  A   B
11     600  500
22     1000 300
```

I mean I get a result by the maximum QTY and not by the maximum date!
What do I need to add to get results by the maximum (last) date ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres doesn't have "first" and "last" aggregation functions.  One method for doing this (without a subquery) uses arrays:

```
select userid,
       (array_agg(qty order by date desc) filter (where product = 'A'))[1] as a,
       (array_agg(qty order by date desc) filter (where product = 'B'))[1] as b
from tab
group by userid;
```

Another method uses `select distinct` with `first_value()`:

```
select distinct userid,
       first_value(qty) over (partition by userid order by product = 'A' desc, date desc) as a,
       first_value(qty) over (partition by userid order by product = 'B' desc, date desc) as b
from tab;
```

With the appropriate indexes, though, `distinct on` might be the fastest approach:

```
select userid,
       max(qty) filter (where product = 'A') as a,
       max(qty) filter (where product = 'B') as b
from (select distinct on (userid, product) t.*
      from tab t
      order by userid, product, date desc
     ) t
group by userid;
```

In particular, this can use an index on `userid, product, date desc)`.  The improvement in performance will be most notable if there are many dates for a given user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DENSE_RANK()` window function in order to filter by the last date per each product and UserID before applying conditional aggregation such as

```
SELECT UserID, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Product='A' THEN QTY END) AS "A",
       MAX(CASE WHEN Product='B' THEN QTY END) AS "B"
  FROM
  (
    SELECT t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Product,UserID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn
      FROM tab t     
  ) q
 WHERE rn = 1 
 GROUP BY UserID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b5ccfa6fc4f0a23e5098cf8f447fc598)</kbd>

presuming all date values are distinct(*no ties occur for dates*)